# Adding autolayout constraints programatically on presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I m presenting a viewcontroller like a popup from my mainviewcontroller on iPad which works fine. But currently I’m setting its prefferedContentSize to fit on screen so when I rotate the size is not autoresized. I need the popupview to be center aligned to the mainviewcontroller with width 97% and height 90% in portrait and landscape. So I’m now trying to add autolayout constraint on my popupViewController but not sure how. Below is the code that I’ve tried so far. This gives me an '*NSInternalInconsistencyException*' error

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    PopUpViewController *popUpController;

}
@end


- (IBAction)showPopUp:(UIButton *)sender {

    popUpController =  [[PopUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];

    popUpController.view.center = self.view.center;
    popUpController.view.layer.cornerRadius =  8.0f;
    popUpController.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    popUpController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    popUpController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;


    popUpController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    popUpController.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

//    CGPoint frameSize = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width*0.97f, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*0.9f);
//    popUpController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(frameSize.x, frameSize.y);
    [self addConstraint];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:popUpController animated:YES completion:nil];


}


-(void)addConstraint
{
    // Width constraint, half of parent view width
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:popUpController.view.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:0.97
                                                           constant:0]];

    // Height constraint, half of parent view height
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:popUpController.view.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:0.9
                                                           constant:0]];

    // Center horizontally
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:popUpController.view.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    // Center vertically
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:popUpController.view.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
}
```

Comment: why you are adding constraints to self.view as it the reference to subViews. It does not need add constraint.When you add any view as subview of self.view then you need to add constraints

Comment: The height and width for 2nd view controller which I'm presenting is not resizing. What should I do to resize? One way is to add size on viewwilltransition, but doesnt look pretty while animating.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, link your constraint to a controller property. Then, to change your constraint value: `self.myConstraint.constant = 0;`.
Also, call `layoutIfNeeded` on your view(s) after changing your constraints values, do it inside a UIAnimation.

Easiest way to manage constraints.

Comment: I'm presenting the secondview controller programatically from 1st view controller, where would I add this constraint?